# Editing Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to capture a table via an array, and iterate through the array multiple times, changing the data in two columns through each iteration. My current code (below) is set up to iterate through the array once, changing the data in two sections (*, 5) and (*, 6). Unfortunately, it displays an error reading

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

```
Sub arraytest()

Dim myArray As Variant

myArray = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Semesters").ListObjects("tblSemester").DataBodyRange.Value

Dim i As Integer
Dim Roww As Integer

Roww = 1

While i < 10
    For Each r In myArray
        myArray(i, 5) = "18/19"
        myArray(i, 6) = "Fall"
        Roww = Roww + 1
        i = 10
    Next
Wend


Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", "U2").Resize(UBound(myArray, 1)).Value = myArray

End Sub
```

How to I edit the code to successfully iterate through the array, changing the data on the specific columns?

Comment: Are you sure that your array has 6 "columns"?

Comment: On what iteration of `i` are you getting the error? When it crashes, hit debug, go to the yellow line and run your arrow over `i`

Comment: Oh when you load an array from a range it starts with 1 and you are trying to get 0 since you do not assign a value the first loop i = 0.  you need to start i at 1.

Comment: @Scott Craner, Unfortunately changing i = 0 did not help.

Comment: Also, there are 21 "columns" in each row

Comment: No it already is `0` you want to put `i=1` before the loop.

Comment: you probably forgot to delete this but the variable `Roww` and all its uses can be removed without ill effect

Comment: And the `i=10` will mean it will only iterate once as it satisfies the while.

Comment: What is the point of the variable `r`? This code makes little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
Sub arraytest()

Dim myArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer

myArray = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Semesters").ListObjects("tblSemester").DataBodyRange.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
    myArray(i, 5) = "18/19"
    myArray(i, 6) = "Fall"
Next

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(myArray, 1), UBound(myArray, 2)).Value = myArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott_Craner! I got something similar working but your solution is more elegant.